# Enabling Multi-Select in ipython-widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I have a development problem. I need to be able to select multiple items at the same time from a drop-down menu in python using ipython-widgets. So far, I have been able to choose an option a single-option widget menu, which upon selection will plot its corresponding statistics. I have pasted my code below, and I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me out.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import panel as pn
pn.extension()


classes= widgets.Dropdown(
description='Products:',
options= list(output_table.class_m.unique())
)


start_year = widgets.BoundedFloatText(
    value=output_table.year.min(),
    min=output_table.year.min(),
    max=output_table.year.max(),
    step=1,
    description='Start Year:',
    disabled=False,
    color='black'
)
end_year = widgets.BoundedFloatText(
    value=output_table.year.max(),
    min=output_table.year.min(),
    max=output_table.year.max(),
    step=1,
    description='End Year:',
    disabled=False,
    color='black'
)


output=widgets.Output()

def response(name, start, end):
    name = classes.value
    output.clear_output()
    df2 = output_table.copy()
   # Filter between min and max years (inclusive)
    df2 = df2[(df2.year >= start) & (df2.year <= end)]
    with output:
        if len(df2) > 0:
            plot1 = df2[df2['class_m'] == name].groupby(['month']).agg({'units':'sum'}).reset_index()
            plot1.plot(x='month', y='units')
            clear_output(wait=True)
            plt.show()
        else:
            print("No data to show for current selection")
def event_handler(change):
    response(change.new, start_year.value, end_year.value)

def start_year_handler(change):
    response(classes.value, change.new, end_year.value)

def end_year_handler(change):
    response(classes.value, start_year.value, change.new)

classes.observe(event_handler, names='value')
start_year.observe(start_year_handler, names = 'value')
end_year.observe(end_year_handler, names = 'value')

display(classes)
display(start_year)
display(end_year)
```

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [SelectMultiple widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#selectmultiple).

```py
w = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    #rows=10,
    description='Fruits',
    disabled=False
)
```

You can shift-click to choose multiple selections, then call `w.value` to get the list of selected values.

Comment: Actually, ````w```` is already a tuple of the selected items which does not have the property ````w.value````.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the new [TagsInput widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#tag-widgets) - it can serve as a more modern multi-select widget, allowing you to add a selection by starting to type text, and remove a selection by clicking the X on the tag. You can of course "observe" its value as with other widgets.

Example:

```
tags = widgets.TagsInput(
    value=['pizza', 'fries'],
    allowed_tags=['pizza', 'fries', 'tomatoes', 'steak'],
    allow_duplicates=False
)
tags
```

Result:
[image]