# In ipywidgets can you enable the Radio Button so that you can select more than one option at the same time?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

In ipywidgets can you enable the Radio Button so that you can select more than one option at the same time?

This is my code:

```
widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'anchovies'],
    value='pineapple', # Defaults to 'pineapple'
   # layout={'width': 'max-content'}, # If the items' names are long
    description='Pizza topping:',
    disabled=False
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling Multi-Select in ipython-widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733810/enabling-multi-select-in-ipython-widgets)